# Cognito - User not able to login when device time zone is EDT and current time is set to that in IST

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using AWS cognito for login in my android app. The login fails in a weird scenario. I set time zone to EDT(GMT-4) and set the time to current IST. When I try to login I get an exception as "CognitoNotAuthorized Exception". Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into similar problems...